# Need to find N value where each sum A+B is different

Tags: matrices, algorithms, summation

I need to find N value (in this case 12, but next time they could more o less) and I need that every sum of two value is a unique number.

In the picture below you can see an easy matrix where there are a lot of duplicate sum (3 times the value 7 on the red line).

Obiovously the N value (12 in the picture) need to be unique themselves.

Is it possible to determine an algorithm to find that?

[image: matrix]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one easy way eplained in the picture below.

The way is to determine the third value by the sum of the first two values and so on, so the last sum of the row is lower than the first sum of the next row.

Do anyone knows another solution to have lower value for the original numbers?

[image]